# Nestjs how to use http request and Websocket at the same time

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nestjs, nestjs-gateways, nestjs-socket.io

I have a controller in Nestjs that handles an HTTP request. There is an IoT device that communicates with the server and sends the latest changes to the server with a post request. At the same time, there is a mobile application that should receive the update in realtime with Websockets.

I know that the HTTP request and Websockets are different concepts in Nestjs, but is there any way to emit an event whenever I receive the HTTP request?

Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is indeed a proper solution for this. You need an `Injectable` that contains an RxJS `Subject`. Whenever your `Controller` receives a value via the POST request, it delegates the value to the injected service. The service then "instructs" the `Subject` to emit the value.
On the other side of the chain, inside your WebSocket `Gateway` `@SubscribeMessage`, you return an RxJS `Observable` - which is derived from the `Subject` - to the connected clients.

More on [Subject](https://next.rxjs.dev/guide/subject) and [Asynchronous responses](https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/gateways#asynchronous-responses)

Here is the [implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-water-fbqey?file=/src/app.service.ts:538-545).

Comment: maybe i don't understand well, but this approach, while great for many aspects i'm sure, doesn't allow to fully perform websocket handling when receiving an https request, or does it ? Like having a socket client join or leave a room when an http request is made, or emit events with the broadcasting method from socket.io ? Or did i miss something ? I mean, doing so would require to identify the socket client on an http request, and that is not handled by the rxjs subjects, right ?